# As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release

Tags: angular

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

Comment: webstorm give me this error every time I try to create a new project with angular-cli

Comment: Perhaps it is time to update to the new version of the CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Comment: I have the latest version of npm 5.5.1 and node 8.9.1

Answer (score 18):

You have to run below command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is incompatibility with the local and global version of your Angular, it is recommended to uninstall and then install.

to uninstall and then clear the cache

npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

then we install the latest version globally and then locally to be able to use ng without problems

Install globally
npm install -g @ angular / cli
Install locally
npm install @ angular / cli

then you check with "ng --version" if you have everything updated, with that you can use for example the "ng add @ angular / material" without problems.

Answer (score -1):

use node version that angular 2 supports.

i have used portable node-v6.17.1-win-x64 zip and by setting set path=extracted-node-v6.17.1-win-x64-folder

make sure node version is according to portable version or existing node version 6 will work.